# Cant connect to MongoDB Atlas based database using spring data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

We are evaluating MongoDB Atlas Cloud for one of our application..  We are facing issue while connecting to DB.. (Mongo shell is connecting and we could import data)

We used Spring-Mongo (http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/)  and used following configuration

Configuration:

```
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}" credentials="MONGO_USER:MONGO_PASS@MONGO_DB"  >
        <mongo:client-options connections-per-host="50" threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="5000" />
     </mongo:mongo-client>
     <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
         <constructor-arg ref="mongoClient"/>
         <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${mongo.dbname}"/>
    </bean>
```

Result:
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream

(value in caps were replaced with actual config. params.)

How we can fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Your java based app cannot connect at all? Or you get this exception after some time of inactivity? Are you connecting using SSL? It would be really helpful if you could provide us with a full stacktrace.

Comment: @RafalG. its not connecting at all.. we are using SSL

Comment: So if it is SSL then keep in mind that it is the JVM that has to know about all the certificates, keystores and such. If you use a regular shell that it already has implemented everything it needs. Your JVM does not. Look into SSL connection issues from JVM to MongoDB. Spring-Data-Mongo is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

When working with the URI ensure that you are stating the authenticationDB to be the "admin" db.